# Bootstrap Multiselect not displaying the dropdown list

Tags: css, knockout.js, bootstrap-multiselect

I have made a custom binding for [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) in Knockout JS.

I am new to custom bindings in Knockout JS.

I have taken [this custom binding jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/1/) for [bootstrap select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and adapted it in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/138/) to be for [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)  and also contain my own viewmodel data. The actual bootstrap multiselect button does display, so the user sees the multiselect element, but upon clicking it, nothing drops down.

Inspecting my webpage shows this output html for the `<select>`:

HTML (this is correct - issue is not with this):

```
    <select multiple="multiple" data-bind="multiselect: _categoryID, 
                optionsText: '_name', 
                optionsValue : '_id', 
                multiselectOptions: { optionsArray: _categories }" class="multiselect" style="display: none;">
<option value="1">Meat-Free Meat</option>
<option value="2">Dairy-Free Dairy</option>
<option value="3">Confectionery</option>
<option value="4">Baking</option>
<option value="5">Dessert</option>
                </select>
```

Here is the bit that goes below the select that the bootstrap multiselect plugin adds (this is not correct - issue is here - see the `<ul>` has no `<li>`'s. :

```
    <div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Dairy-Free Dairy, Confectionery" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="multiselect-selected-text">Dairy-Free Dairy, Confectionery</span> 
<b class="caret"></b>
</button>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
</ul></div>
```

Why does clicking the [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) button not cause a dropdown to appear? AKA why is the the `<ul>` empty?
**EDIT: All work on this question can now be tried in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/138/)**

Comment: It would be better if you can provide your custom multiselect binding code here. or a fiddle for not working scenario.

Comment: @Dandy I have created the jsfiddle and added it to the bottom of my question, however am having trouble importing the bootstrap multiselect external resource

Comment: You use rawgit to import modules from git. You also need jQuery. I've updated your Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/138/
However, pressing run loads a new display, which is weird.

Comment: @RoyJ Fantastic, thank you. I have updated my question with that js fiddle now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

`$(element).multiselect('refresh');`

with

`$(element).multiselect('rebuild')`;

[Working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/vyrafntw/1/)

Comment: Wow. I had already moved on to an alternative (no custom binding, instead, using the foreach binding on the select to insert the `<option>`'s), but this is way better because it can automatically update the selected items. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you. Refer the link "http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/". This documentation is crystal clear and covers all options of bootstrap multi-select.

Answer (score 0):

The select has `display:none` because it is hidden. Bootstrap provides a replacement front-end for it. You interact with the Bootstrap widget, and it acts as a proxy to update the state of the "real" select.

I do not know why the dropdown is not showing in your app. As you note, it works in the Fiddle. My best guess is that your list of options isn't structured properly.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a jsfiddle to the question, just having trouble importing the external resource for bootstrap multiselect